# Copying files to remote desktops using batch file

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, unix

I have 89 servers on which I am remotely connected that is I can access files of these system. There is one common folder or java application placed in all 89 desktops. We need to regularly update the folder whenever we have to make any changes in it which is now manual task i.e. we update each and every desktop manually.

Is there any mechanism through which we can update the folder in all 89 desktops at once and also we need the failure log if occurred for any desktop.

Comment: You don't have login scripts within your company?  You could also use the administrative share to access them as well.

Comment: Oops, I answered considering only the windows and batch-file tags (as I was currently filtering question with that). But I see you tagged with linux / unix also ?? Are you sure about that ? Because answer will be OS-dependent... Could you clarify ?

Answer (score 0):

If your servers have some numerical name scheme, say `SERVER_1`, `SERVER_2`, ... then you can copy some file with:

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,%lastnum%) do call :sp %%a
echo done!
goto :eof

:sp
set machine=SERVER_%1
copy c:\some\folder\somefile \\%machine%\C$\some\folder 
goto :eof
```

If you don't have a numerical naming scheme and instead a list of names, just gather these in a text file an replace by a `FOR /F`, iterating through each line and fetching the name.